# Не могу правильно написать код для подсчета среднего значения в кортеже кортежей в Python

Tags: python, словари, кортежи

Уже более 5 часов пытаюсь найти решение задачи по подсчету среднего значения ключей в кортеже. Суть такая:

- ввожу строки с именем, а потом значения, соответствующие элементам строки.
- Упаковываю все это в кортежи

Далее, мне нужно пробежаться по всему кортежу и найти среднее значение у ключей с одинаковым именем.
Далее нужно создать новый кортеж где будут только оставшиеся уникальные имена, но уже со средним значением.

Застрял в цикле где одинаковых ключей больше, чем 2, так как не знаю, как написать правильный код при подсчете среднего при большем кол-ве

Пример

Input:

```
a  a  b  b b  b c d
10 20 50 0 67 8 8 10
```

Output:

```
(('a', 10.0), ('a', 20.0), ('b', 50.0), ('b', 0.0), ('b', 67.0), ('b', 8.0), ('c', 8.0), ('d', 10.0)) 

{'a': 15.0, 'b': 9.666666666666668, 'c': 8.0, 'd': 10.0}
```

Как видите b считает неверно, так как в цикле берет среднее только между двумя элементами, а не суммой между всех элементов.

Сам код

```
text1=input()
text2=input()
names=text1.split()
grade0=text2.split()
grade=[float(item) for item in grade0]
base=tuple(zip(names,grade))
a=[]

count_dict={}
i=1
for name1,grade1 in base:
    count=count_dict.get(name1,0)
    if count != 0:
        i+=1
    else:
        i=1
    count_dict[name1]=(grade1+count)/i

print(base, count_dict)
```

Благодарю

Answer (score 4):

Вариант с накоплением в словаре списков значений с последующим вычислением среднего.

```
text1 = 'a  a  b  b b  b c d'
text2 = '10 20 50 0 67 8 8 10'
out = {}
for x, y in zip(text1.split(), map(float, text2.split())):
    out.setdefault(x, []).append(y)
out = {k: sum(v) / len(v) for k, v in out.items()}
print(out)
```

```
{'a': 15.0, 'b': 31.25, 'c': 8.0, 'd': 10.0}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо сначала собирать данные, сколько каких ключей введено и какова их сумма, а уже после вычислять среднее значение.

Вот один из примеров данной реализации:

```
text1 = input()
text2 = input()
names=text1.split()
grade0=text2.split()
grade=[float(item) for item in grade0]
base=tuple(zip(names,grade))

count_dict = {}
sum_dict = {}
for name1, grade1 in base:
    count = count_dict.get(name1, 0)
    if count != 0:
        count_dict[name1] += 1
        sum_dict[name1] += grade1
    else:
        count_dict[name1] = 1
        sum_dict[name1] = grade1

for item in count_dict.items():
    sum_dict[item[0]] = sum_dict[item[0]] / count_dict[item[0]]

print(sum_dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
text1 = 'a  a  b  b b  b c d'
text2 = '10 20 50 0 67 8 8 10'

d = {}
for el in zip(text1.split(),text2.split()):
    z = []
    if el[0] in d:
        z = d[el[0]]
        z.append(float(el[1]))
        d[el[0]] = z
    else:
        z.append(float(el[1]))
        d[el[0]] = z
d1 = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    d1[k] = sum(v) / len(v)

print(d1)
```

---

```
{'a': 15.0, 'b': 31.25, 'c': 8.0, 'd': 10.0}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
text1 = 'a  a  b  b b  b c d'
text2 = '10 20 50 0 67 8 8 10'

names = text1.split()
grade0 = text2.split()
base = tuple(zip(names, map(float, grade0)))

dct = {}
for nam in set(names):
    c = [y for x, y in base if x == nam]
    dct[nam] = sum(c) / len(c)
print(dct)
```